# Efficient Dockerfile for many apt-get packages

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I've created a Dockerfile for an application I'm building that has a lot of large apt-get package dependencies. It looks something like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:15.10

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
  lots-of-big-packages

RUN install_my_code.sh
```

As I develop my application, I keep coming up with unanticipated package dependencies. However, since all the packages are in one Dockerfile instruction, even adding one more breaks the cache and requires the whole lot to be downloaded and installed, which takes forever. I'm wondering if there's a better way to structure my Dockerfile?

One thought would be to put a separate `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y` command for each package, but running apt-get update lots of times probably eats up any savings.

The simplest solution would be to just add a second `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y` right after the first as a catchall for all of the unanticipated packages, but that divides the packages in an unintuitive way. (ie, "when I realized I needed it") I suppose I could combine them when dependencies are more stable, but I find I'm always overly optimistic about when that is.

Anyway, if anyone has a better way to structure it I'd love to hear it. (all of my other ideas run against the Docker principles of reproducibility)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to run `apt-get update` only once within the Dockerfile, typically before any other `apt-get` commands.

You could just first have the large list of known programs to install, and if you come up with a new one then just add a new `RUN apt-get install -y abc` to you Dockerfile and let docker continue form the previously cached command. Periodically (once a week, one a month?) you could re-organize them as you see fit or just run everything in a single command.

> I suppose I could combine them when dependencies are more stable, but
>   I find I'm always overly optimistic about when that is.

Oh you actually mentioned this solution already, anyway there is no harm doing these "tweaks" every now and then. Just run `apt-get update` only once.

Comment: Check out https://docs.docker.com/engine/articles/dockerfile_best-practices/ for why apt-get update should/has to be run in the same instruction as upgrade (scroll down to the apt-get header)

Comment: Good points about caching and how it is not always intended. "Because the apt-get update is not run, your build can potentially get an outdated version of the curl and nginx packages." While this is true, you can accidentally use old curl even if you have `update` and `install` in the same command if you continue using same cached layers for months. Or if you add `RUN update && install nginx` after `install curl` you can have old curl but new nginx. Maybe this is one more reason to concatenate all installs to a single command.